# yii\db\Query::limit() function not limiting the records - Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, limit

Below is the code I'm using to get data from my table(s) for creating REST api.

```
$query = new yii\db\Query();
$sql = $query
    ->select('a.vehicle_number, b.device_id, b.dated, b.speed, b.ignition, b.latitude, b.longitude')
    ->from('tk103_devices a, tk103_current_location b')
    ->where('a.device_id = b.device_id AND a.transporter_id='.$id)
    ->orderBy(['a.vehicle_number'=>SORT_ASC])
    ->limit(1);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'=>$sql
    ]);
return array('count_flag'=>$countFlag, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider->getModels());
```

I had set the limit(1) which does "**Sets the LIMIT part of the query.**" as per Yii official doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#limit()-detail.

When I am executing the above query, all the records are being returned by the dataprovider.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some homework by myself, I find solution to the above problem by changing the code as below:

```
$query = new yii\db\Query();
$sql = $query
    ->select('a.vehicle_number, b.device_id, b.dated, b.speed, b.ignition, b.latitude, b.longitude')
    ->from('tk103_devices a, tk103_current_location b')
    ->where('a.device_id = b.device_id AND a.transporter_id='.$id)
    ->orderBy(['a.vehicle_number'=>SORT_ASC])
    ->one();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'=>$sql
    ]);
return array('count_flag'=>$countFlag, 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider);
```

As per my scenario, I wanted to retrieve only first record. So, I used `one()` instead of `limit(1)`.

Secondly, I was returning dataProvider as `$dataProvider->getModels()`. I changed this to `$dataProvider` only. Since **"ActiveDataProvider does not take care at query limit."** as per [Fabrizio Caldarelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314488/fabrizio-caldarelli)'s answer below (or) above, it was returning all retrieved records.

Hope that helps someone having related issues.

---

For previous code to work, you must see [Fabrizio Caldarelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314488/fabrizio-caldarelli)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427467/4512651) below (or) above.

Comment: But $sql passed to 'query' attribute of ActiveDataProvider is an ActiveRecord, not an instance of ActiveQuery how required by ActiveDataProvider.

Comment: I extended my models class with `yii\db\Query`

Answer (score 2):

ActiveDataProvider does not take care at query limit.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#active-data-provider

Extract from above link:

> Note: If a query already specifies the orderBy clause, the new
>   ordering instructions given by end users (through the sort
>   configuration) will be appended to the existing orderBy clause. Any
>   existing limit and offset clauses will be overwritten by the
>   pagination request from end users (through the pagination
>   configuration).

So, since you have fixed data, use ArrayDataProvider:

```
$data = $query
    ->select('a.vehicle_number, b.device_id, b.dated, b.speed, b.ignition, b.latitude, b.longitude')
    ->from('tk103_devices a, tk103_current_location b')
    ->where('a.device_id = b.device_id AND a.transporter_id='.$id)
    ->orderBy(['a.vehicle_number'=>SORT_ASC])
    ->limit(1)
    ->all();

$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider(['allModels' => $data]);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your time to my issue. However I cannot use `ArrayDataProvider` as per [Yii doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html)'s statement, **Compared to yii\data\ActiveDataProvider, ArrayDataProvider could be less efficient because it needs to have $allModels ready.** I posted answer myself and I think it's a better version I could use. However, I appreciate your answer. +1 for that.